# Create Alert when an user creates a new SharePoint Online site in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow, power-automate, sharepoint-alerts

Is there a way to create an alert that lets me know when an user creates a new SharePoint Online Site?

Comment: Hi @Anthony, does my answer below help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Site Design, set it as the default (for Modern Team and/or Comm) which triggers a Power Automate flow or Azure LogicApp which sends an email, sends notification to a Team channel, etc.

https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/get-started-create-site-design

Answer (score 0):

As per [Get all site collections listed in SharePoint Admin center using Rest / Search / Graph api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297239/get-all-site-collections-listed-in-sharepoint-admin-center-using-rest-search), all site collections created in tenant are stored in list "DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS".

So, you can create a simple flow like below using tenant admin account to notify user on new site creation:

[image]

Where Site Address is SP admin site URL like: `https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/` & List Name is `DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_SITES_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS`.

**Output**:

[image]