# Automatically set properties on a web site after creation

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are in need of setting a property in every web site when they are created in SharePoint Online and would like to automate this.

In the past I've done this with SharePoint Ad-ins and used SPWebEventReciever to trigger when a web is created in on-prem environments. This is now deprecated and they expect to use a Webhook. Webhooks only appear to be available for Lists so this doesn't work unless we create quite the kludge.

Is there a proper method to fire off code or a script once a website is created in SharePoint Online?

Comment: Do you want to set properties when new "site" (site collection) is created in SharePoint Online tenant? Do you have access to Power automate flows? Try this and let me know if it works for you: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297247/create-alert-when-an-user-creates-a-new-sharepoint-online-site-in-office-365/297249#297249

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to achieve this in Power Automate?:

Create a flow in Power Automate where a new page will be created by an HTTP Request with JSON.
You can update the page properties using the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action.

```
Method: POST
Uri: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(1)
Headers: 
{
  "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "If-Match": "*",
  "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
}
Body: 
{
  "__metadata": {"type":"SP.Data.SitePagesItem"},
  "Title": "Custom title set by flow"
}
```

You can add one more actions & perform an update operation, pass the item ID (in Uri) from dynamic data of the previous action used to create a page.