# Send an customized email when new site is created in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, power-automate, communication-site

Is there any web hook or Power Automate trigger available when a new site is created in SharePoint Online?

Goal is to send a customized email to site owners when the new site is created.

Newly created sites will be Modern SharePoint Online sites (Communication site).

I could not find any trigger for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Get all site collections listed in SharePoint Admin center using Rest / Search / Graph api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297239/get-all-site-collections-listed-in-sharepoint-admin-center-using-rest-search), all site collections created in tenant are stored in list "DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS".

So, you can create a simple flow like below using tenant admin account to notify user on new site creation:

[image]

Where Site Address is SP admin site URL like: `https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/` & List Name is `DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_SITES_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS`.

**Output**:

[image]

**Update from comments**:

I just tried creating new communication site in my tenant & received email like:

[image]

Comment: I created the flow and then created the new site but the flow is not triggered. I can see the new site name using REST API

Comment: Are you able to access the mentioned list from `https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx` page? Did you use the correct list name in flow (just to make sure as there are few lists with similar names)? How much time you waited after creating a new site?

Comment: Yes I am able to see the list. I waited for around 2 hours. This is the list name.
DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_SITES_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS

Comment: Do you see the site name added in above list? I tried above flow approx 2 months ago & it was working for me.

Comment: Yes, I can see the new site name. I will check again after some time. but thanks for the help

Comment: I just tried creating a new site & received an email. check screenshot in updated answer. Try creating flow & using connection with SharePoint tenant administrator user account once.